# F5 on WCF project in C#/VS2008 produces WcfSvcHost.exe error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wcf

My project is in VS2008/C# and a WCF service library. Trying to test the service, hit F5. Get the WcfSvcHost.exe error and this is more deatails below

```
Error Signature:
AppName: wcfsvchost.exe  AppVer: 9.0.622.1152    ModName: mscorwks.dll
ModVer: 2.0.50727.3082   Offset: 00080012
```

The IDE get back to normal code mode and the WcfTestClient.exe is launched with my service calls, but of course I can invoke any as my service failed to launch.

I had to remove spybot and teatimer.exe and reboot my system and now I get this error

Additional Error:

```
An unhandled win32 exception occured in WcfSvcHost.exe[5132]
```

Additional Info:
I do not think it is associated with VS2008. I tried launching my WcfSvcHost.exe on its own and I got the following error

```
Unhandled exception at 0x01e30430 in WcfSvcHost.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x01e30430.
```

Log from Event Viewer

```
Faulting application wcfsvchost.exe, version 9.0.622.1152, stamp 488f124d, faulting module ntdll.dll, version 5.1.2600.5755, stamp 49901d48, debug? 0, fault address 0x00011129.
```

Comment: Are there any more details on the error?

Comment: Andy White, I updated my question by adding additional error info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing the details of the error, it's my opinion that this is not a `wcfsvchost` issue, but an issue with a corrupt `ntdll.dll` file.

Please read **[this information](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/a/ntdlldll.htm)** for details on how to solve this.

Comment: I agree with your assessment +1

Comment: running sfc /scannow to determine if any original DLL's are corrupt or not

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which one of these solved it but this is what I did
1. removed google toolbar for IE

2. Removed Git extensions
3. Reboot machine
4. run sfc /scannow  from sart->run

This seems to have done the trick for now, but...